# v-calendar update-pages event called repeatedly

Tags: vuejs3, v-calendar.io

Using [v-calendar version 3.0.3](https://vcalendar.io/), I'm trying to change the `attributes` collection whenever a page is updated. In order to do that, I update `attributes` collection inside my `update:pages` event, and I notice that the event is called repeatedly. This is illustrated here, if you view the Console, it gets lots of `update {counter}` logs: https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-sun-7vqvj6?file=/src/App.vue

```
<template>
  <v-calendar :attributes="attributes" @update:pages="updatePages">
  </v-calendar>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
      counter: 0,
      attributes: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    updatePages() {
      this.counter++;
      console.table("update " + this.counter);
      this.attributes = [];
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very simple

Changing `this.attributes = []` inside `updatePages()` causes dead loop, since your `v-calendar` is bound to `attributes` and emits `update:pages` every time when `attributes` changes.

```
   updatePages() {
      this.counter++;
      console.table("update " + this.counter);
      this.attributes = [];
    },
```

Just remove this line. You will have to find another way to do it.

**UPDATE**

You can prevent dead loop by checking in the `updatePages()` if the page was really changed, and only then update the `attributes`

```
 data() {
    return {
      counter: 0,
      attributes: [],
      lastMonth: 0
    };
  },
  methods: {
    updatePages(e) {
      if (e[0].month !== this.lastMonth) {
        console.log(`month: ${this.lastMonth} -> ${e[0].month}`);
        this.lastMonth = e[0].month;
        this.attributes = [];
      }      
    },
  },
```

Updated [Playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-hofstadter-3c8net?file=/src/App.vue)

Comment: Do you know how else to set the `attributes` dynamically? Thanks for your help by the way!

Comment: Clarify, what do you want to set dynamically?

Comment: I want to set the attributes dynamically. So if a user changes the calendar view from May to June, I want to then do an ajax request to the server to get the events that are scheduled in the database for June to render them onto the calendar.